# mongodb maxDistance attribute not querying proper radius

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

#### Inserted Into Database

> db.users.insert({"first_name":"alex","temp":"ossington-dundas","loc":{"lat":43.64911870668915,"lon":-79.42063808441162}})
> db.users.insert({"first_name":"heather","temp":"orillia","loc":{"lat":44.610634506093,"lon":-79.44514274597168}})
> db.users.insert({"first_name":"lindsay","temp":"404-davis dr.","loc":{"lat":44.06834703351985,"lon":-79.4205093383789}})
> db.users.insert({"first_name":"vanessa","temp":"bathurst-lawrence","loc":{"lat":43.71925681186761,"lon":-79.42960739135742}})
> db.users.insert({"first_name":"ariel","temp":"yonge-dundas","loc":{"lat":43.65477003252322,"lon":-79.388108253479}})
> db.users.insert({"first_name":"john","temp":"yonge-dundas","loc":{"lat":43.65477003252322,"lon":-79.388108253479}})

#### Indexed Database:

> db.users.ensureIndex({loc:"2d"})

#### Queried from Database:

> db.users2.find({"loc":{ $near: [ 43.65477003252322, -79.388108253479 ]}}).pretty()

#### Result: SUCCESS!

## The Problem: $maxdistance

Now, I want to have a max distance of 10 miles (preferably kms) set on these queries. so the query should look like this:

> db.users.find({"loc":{ $near: [ 43.65477003252322, -79.388108253479 ],$maxDistance: 10/3959}});

but maxdistance is not working correctly. What seems to be the problem? also is there something more efficient I should be using? like $centerSphere Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing into radians which is the returned measurement from legacy coodinate pairs incorrectly. The divisor should be 3963.2 for miles or 6378.1 for kilometers in conversion. If you just inserted the data as GeoJSON to begin with, then the measurement is always returned in meters as the standard.

But your main problem is you have your coordinates the "wrong way around". The order is "longitude" then "latitude", so you need:

```js
{ "$near": [ -79.388108253479, 43.65477003252322 ], "$maxDistance": 10/3963.2 }
```

And again, if you had used GeoJSON in the first place then again you would not have the confusion as the order is "forced" unlike the way you have worked around it with a "lat" and "lon" key in the legacy pair fashion.

Not to mention that when measuring distances on the "globe" of the earth, then you should be usign [`$nearSphere`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) which compensates correctly.